# Assign a specific hour to a Calendar

Tags: java, android, calendar

I want to test if a string converted to Calendar is before or after now.
I don't understand why this is not working:

```
public final static SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT_RESERVATION_HOUR = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");    
String str = "14:00";

Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar selected = Calendar.getInstance();
//avoiding try/catch in this post
selected.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (int) DATE_FORMAT_RESERVATION_HOUR.parse(str).getTime());
// selected = now : 7352-05-18 00:49:33 (instead of 2013-06-17 14:00:00
Log.d("test", "after?" + selected.after(now));
```

I would like "selected" to be now, but with the hour specified in str.
Any help welcomed!
Thanks

Comment: You mean you want to selected to be in the format as specified?

Comment: no, I want selected to be equals to now (so the time returned by Calendar.getInstance() but with the hour set to 14:00 in this case

Comment: When I try to parse it, I get a ParseException saying `Unparseable date: "14:00"`.  You don't get the same?

Comment: So you need to set hour and minute as specified in your str, right? But remaining everything as it is?

Comment: If you want only the hour to be set as your custom and all the other time as current, then try this:
Change String str="14:00" to String str = "14" 
and then 
selected.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(str));

Comment: Yes that is what I want to achieve @Mr.777 but str could be 14:35 for example. 
so I did 
    selected.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(str.split(":")[0]));
    selected.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(str.split(":")[1]));
And it works, thanks!

Comment: Glad I am able to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why this is not working:

[getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29):

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

This is not the value which you want to set the `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` for the desired result.

1. You can use the deprecated [getHours()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDate%28%29) in your case :

   ```
   selected.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 
              (int) DATE_FORMAT_RESERVATION_HOUR.parse(str).getHours());
   ```

**2. If the variable `str` will always be in that format , then you can also do this :**

```
    selected.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(str.split(":")[0]));
```

Comment: thanks, but selected is not assigned to the new value after this change. Also, I would prefer to go for a not-deprecated method :/

Comment: *selected is not assigned to the new value after this change.* What does that mean ?

Comment: ok I have it working, see my comments above, thanks for the help